# How can i get current Fragment of FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

```
public class FolioPageFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    private List<SpineReference> mSpineReferences;
    private Book mBook;
    private String mEpubFileName;
    private boolean mIsSmilAvailable;
    private FolioPageFragment mFolioPageFragment;

    public FolioPageFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<SpineReference> spineReferences,
                                    Book book, String epubFilename, boolean isSmilAvilable) {
        super(fm);
        this.mSpineReferences = spineReferences;
        this.mBook = book;
        this.mEpubFileName = epubFilename;
        this.mIsSmilAvailable = isSmilAvilable;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        mFolioPageFragment = FolioPageFragment.newInstance(position, mBook, mEpubFileName, mIsSmilAvailable);
        return mFolioPageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSpineReferences.size();
    }


    public FolioPageFragment getCurrentFragment(){
         return mFolioPageFragment;
    }
}



 It   doesn't   give   me   the   correct   current   fragment.
```

Is there any  way  so  that i can get the current Fragment. 
I have changed the FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter.
The below method doesn't give the current Fragment.
Evert time the instance is created i'm storing it in the global variable still it does not work for me.

```
private Fragment getFragment(int pos) {
        return getSupportFragmentManager().
                findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.folioPageViewPager + ":" + (pos));
    }
```

Comment: Check answer with "makeFragmentName" here:
[Retrieve a Fragment from a ViewPager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager)

Answer (score 1):

This probably don't work, because getItem() can return next/previous fragment. Try to make array of fragments, store there created fragments and retrieve from array current.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` has a different loading that you've expected to have.

1. When it's loaded and set a `position` it will load: the fragment at `position - 1`, fragment at `position`, fragment at `position + 1`. So in your case the global variable will hold the fragment at `position+1`.
2. When you swipe, the last loaded fragment will be `position - 1` or `position + 1` depending on the scroll direction.

What you should do, is to keep a `HashMap` with the position & the fragment for that position. Then based on the current position you'll query the `HashMap` and return the fragment.

You should also detect swipe/page changes and remove destroyed fragments from the `HasMap` so it won't keep reference to them, thus memory issues.